# Which Linux distribution has up to date repositories option for software developers?

Tags: linux, operating-system

I am using Ubuntu for developing my c++ and others software .But the annoying thing about Ubuntu is most of the repositories it has are not the latest version .For example gcc compiler which I from

```
 sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Have version 4.6.x which not the latest version. I know Some people may say that I can Install GCC from the source and its not a problem . 
But I want to know , Is there a Linux Distribution which already have all the latest repositories?

Comment: You might consider `Debian/Unstable`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Arch Linux](https://www.archlinux.org/) prides itself on having the bleeding edge in its distribution. The downside is that things sometimes [break between releases](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/FAQ#Q.29_Is_Arch_Linux_a_stable_distribution.3F_Will_I_get_frequent_breakage.3F), so if you aren't at least slightly confident in using Linux + the command line it isn't necessarily for you.

Comment: Exactly. Arch is the way to go, I like to tell people that Arch is the true developer's distribution.